# Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol error message when compiling program using classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, linker

I just installed VS 2013 this week (Have been using 2012 version before). I got an error in this first program I am trying to do using classes. I tried to read other threads with similar error but none of the answers have worked for me so far. This is supposed to be a program that is based on a stack.

Error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  Stackt.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Stackt<char>::Stackt<char>(int)" (??0?$Stackt@D@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

stackt.h

```
#ifndef STACKT_H           
#define STACKT_H       
template <class Type>
class Stackt
{
public:
    Stackt(int n = 128);
private:
    Type *stack;
    int top, max;
};
#endif
```

stack.cpp

```
#include "Stackt.h"
template <class Type>
Stackt<Type>::Stackt(int n)
{
    max = n;
    stack = new Type[max];
    top = -1;
}
```

source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stackt.h"

void main()
{
    Stackt<char> s1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

Template implementations must be available to the compiler at compile time. You must define `template<typename T> Stackt<T>::Stackt(int n)` in the header file.